Bigquery - what happens when you archive data from a partitioned table?
In Bigquery, curious to know the impact of archiving and deleting rows from a table where:

The partition limit is 100 partitions
There are 1000 unique integer values in the paritition column
The rows associated with the oldest 950 values are archived into another table, leaving only rows associated with the 50 newest values
The rows associated with the 50 newest values, before older data was archived, existed in a spillover partition

Do the rows associated with the 50 remaining values get re-allocated to their own partitions? The documentation is not clear on this.
